# Mongoose nested populate query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to return a list of coupons that are associated with a specific userid and populate the _merchant references.

This query correctly populates the _merchant refs.  If I could add:

where coupon.users.contains(myuserid) to my query that would get what I need

```
db.couponModel.find().populate('_merchant').exec(function(err, coupons) { 
    res.send(coupons);
});
```

Or this query finds the correct coupons that I need.  If I could add:

populate(_merchant) to my query that would also get what I need.

```
db.userModel.findById(req.params.id).populate('coupons').exec(function(err, user) {
    res.send(user.coupons)
});
```

Schemas

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true , unique: true },
    coupons: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Coupon' }]
});

var couponSchema = new Schema({
    _merchant: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Merchant', required: true },
    couponid: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    users: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]


});

var merchantSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true , unique: true }
    coupons: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Coupon' }],

});
```

I need some hybrid of these two queries to get what I want.

Comment: I guess populating on embedded document of embedded document is not supported yet. See https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/601#issuecomment-6520568

Comment: I think it's supported in the release as of a couple days ago but there's no docs for it yet.  Any hacks to get around it?  Using $in perhaps?

Comment: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/pull/1292

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out using the $all option.  Examples here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/test/query.test.js#L396  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/#_S_all

Final query code:

```
db.couponModel.find({users: {$all:[req.params.id]}}).populate('_merchant').exec(function(err, coupons) { console.log(coupons); })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **$all** option.
db.couponModel.find({users: {$all:[req.params.id]}}).populate('_merchant').exec(function(err, coupons) { console.log(coupons); })